# Remove padding from custom action bar

Tags: android

i want to remove the extra padding in custom action bar. I am using android SDK 15. 
[image]

This is my code for inflating action bar.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

    View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.title, null);
    mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
    mActionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
   }
```

this is my styles.xml

```
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Toolbar</item>

</style>

<style name="Widget.Toolbar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
    <item name="contentInsetStart">0dp</item>

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's take a try ! It works for me.

```
 mActionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);

 Toolbar parent =(Toolbar) mCustomView.getParent();
 parent.setContentInsetsAbsolute(0,0);
```

Comment: setContentInsetsAbsolute is API level 21 mine is 15,